# Error TS2305: Module @types/angular has no exported member 'cookies'

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, cookies, jestjs

I am having an issue with cookies not being defined in angular scope.

`npm run start` builds and starts the app just fine,
but when trying to run `npm test` that executes `jest` command, I am getting this error:

> `Test suite failed to run app/components/Component1/Component1.ts:1:10
>
> - error TS2305: Module '"../../../../../node_modules/@types/angular"' has no exported member 'cookies'.`

in `Component1.ts` there is this import: `import { cookies } from 'angular';`

Build and run - ok.
Testing - not ok.

If you know where the issue can be hidden, please help :) Thank you.

my package.json:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "angular": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-cookies": "1.8.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.2.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/angular-cookies": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
    "angular-mock": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.8.2",
    "angularjs-jest": "^0.1.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: production and development builds are different from test builds, errors in test builds will not affect your other builds in any way. The error simply says that `angular` has no exported member `cookies`

Answer (score 0):

solution for my issue was adding `angular-cookies` to `tsconfig.test.json` file.
I still do not understand why `angular-cookies` since source code and production build is taking types and definitions from `angular` package (and through IDE I can link to angular module rather than angular-cookies).
But that's life is all about - mysteries.

```js
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest",
      "angular-cookies" --> THIS VERY LINE SOLVED MY ISSUE
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "index.d.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```